# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Board.offsetWidth')

Tags: webpack, phantomjs, mocha.js, karma-runner, chai

I'm writing a test that uses an canvas from a page. When i try to get the offsetWidth of this object, an error occurs. If I understand correctly, the problem is that the tests do not know where to get the html file from.

My karma config:

```
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config');
module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({
basePath: '',
frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai', 'sinon'],
files: [
  'src/index.pug',
  'test/**/*.ts'
],
exclude: [
],
preprocessors: {
  'test/**/*.ts': ['webpack'],
  'src/index.pug': ['pug', 'html2js']
},
webpack: {
  module: webpackConfig.module,
  resolve: webpackConfig.resolve
},
reporters: ['progress'],
port: 9876,
colors: true,
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
autoWatch: true,
browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
singleRun: true,
concurrency: Infinity
})
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. You need to have a DOM available, which means you either need to run the tests in a browser or make a fake browser environment in Node using JSDOM. That part is OK.

But we haven't seen any of your tests. If they assume that some kind of setup should be in place, for instance mounting the Board object on some DOM node then you need a setup phase before your test that creates this new node, adds it to the DOM, runs the Board init code,  etc.

*edit, got code:* So [after looking at the code in question](https://codepen.io/Zwlr/project/editor/ZwKnxR/) I found this line in `Board.ts`:

```
this.canvasBoard = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementsByClassName('game__board')[0];
```

This assumes that there exists a DOM node with a class `game__board`. To make any tests work that relies on this, you would need to create it (and clean it up after each test):

```
beforeEach(() => {
    const nodeNames = ['game__board', 'game__btn_play', 'game__btn_pause']; // add the rest ...
    nodeNames.forEach( (name) => {
        const elem = document.createElement('div');
        elem.classList.add(name);
        document.body.appendChild(elem);
     });
})

afterEach(() => {
    document.body.innerHTML = '';
});
```

That part above will create the required canvas node, but another thing is that your code is incorrect AFAIK. The line mentioned should be wrapped in a `constructor` function for it to run when the object is created.

So change the incorrect init code

```
this.canvasBoard = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementsByClassName('game__board')[0];
```

to

```
constructor() {
    this.canvasBoard = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementsByClassName('game__board')[0];
}
```

You can validate that the first [is incorrect on the TypeScript PlayGround](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20default%20class%20Board%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20public%20canvasBoard%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20board%3A%20Array%3CArray%3Cnumber%3E%3E%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20this.canvasBoard%20%3D%20%3CHTMLCanvasElement%3Edocument.getElementsByClassName('game__board')%5B0%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%09public%20fillBoard%20%3D%20(x%2C%20y)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09for%20(var%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20x%3B%20i%20%2B%3D%201)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09%09this.board.push(%5B%5D)%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09for%20(var%20j%20%3D%200%3B%20j%20%3C%20y%3B%20j%20%2B%3D%201)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09%09this.board%5Bi%5D.push(0)%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D).

Comment: Thank you. Here is a link to the part of the project, perhaps it will help you answer more accurately: https://codepen.io/Zwlr/project/editor/ZwKnxR/

Comment: Hmm ... I just realized the code above answers what you asked, but it is not alone enough to fix your error. If you look at the test code, you construct three objects, but both the view and the controller are unused in the test. Yet, the error comes from the unused controller part

Comment: @AZawalar Should be complete now. Please uvote/mark as answer if it answers your problem.

Comment: Thanks, it helped! But now when the test starts, another error occurs.
Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'elem.addEventListener'). For clarity, I copied my entire view to codepen. Please, look again

Comment: The error is quite simple. It says that you are trying to add an even to an element that does not exist. That means, from your code, that the nodes you are trying to do something with has not been found. 

And that is not strange :-) My test code above just create one node - the root node ("game__board"). You still need to create nodes for all the other elements you reference: `game__btn_play`, `game__btn_stop`, etc. Just copy the lines in the `beforeEach()` and change the string.

Comment: Well thank you. And what for this code is necessary? afterEach(() => { document.body.innerHTML = ''; });

Comment: That empties the entire DOM, so no changes should be necessary.

Comment: Okay, but maybe there is another way of working with the DOM? For example, adding elements through the html2js preprocessor? The thing is, the way you've laid out needs to copy elements from one place to another.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Copy what elements? I am not copying anything. If you mean that the class names used are duplicated and you want to avoid the maintenance overhead, then simply expose them as static props on the class that you reference in the test code. But as I said, I am not sure I know what you are saying :-)

Comment: If you mean you don't want to duplicate the html markup from your application, then you are out of luck, as the dom in Karma is empty when you run the tests. If you need any markup present for your app to use, then you will need to supply it yourself. One way to avoid coding it in javascript is of course just to extract the html required to some file that you then can load and inject into your tests, and proceed to replace the `innerHtml` of the `body` node with that. But that starts getting out of scope for your question ...